# Get column data when clicked on row with Razor and JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have table that is built dynamically with Razor in MVC.

I want to be able to click on the a row and get the value of lets's say the first column ID.

Right now it's getting all the columns but I don't know too much Javascript or how it's stored with text.

Anyways what I'm looking for is to get a certain column on the row I clicked.

Razor MVC

```
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter"> 
<thead> 
<tr> 
    <th>ID</th> 
    <th>Owner</th> 
</tr> 
</thead> 
<tbody> 
@for(int i=0; i<Model.changes.Count(); i++)
{
<tr> 
    <td>@Model.changes[i].ID</td> 
    <td>@Model.changes[i].Owner</td> 
</tr> 
}
</tbody> 
</table>
```

Javascript

```
<script>

    var table = $("#myTable tr");

    table.click(function () {
        alert($(this).text());
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**nth-child**](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/),

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/2hyjF/2/)**

```
var table = $("#myTable tr");

table.click(function () {
    alert($(':nth-child(1)',  this).text());
});​
```

Comment: Hmm, this isn't working for me. All the alert shows is :nth-child(1).

Comment: Check it now, I just fixed it.